# If $f(a v) = a^2 f(v) $ and $B (v,w) := f(v+w) - f(v) - f(w) $is a bilinear form then $f$ is a quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I read the following statement in Conway's book on quadratic forms and tried to prove it:

A function $f$ is a quadratic form if and only if $f(a\textbf {v}) = a^2 f(\textbf{v}) $ and $B (\textbf{v},\textbf{w}) := f(\textbf{v} + \textbf{w}) - f(\textbf{v}) - f(\textbf{w})$ is a bilinear form.

(Here $\textbf {v}$ is a real number $n$ dimensional vector. The function $f$ is a quadratic form if $f( (x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} x_i x_j$ for constants $\alpha_{ij}$)

I proved necessity, but I am having problems with sufficiency. I know the function will be of the form $f( (0,\cdots,x_i,\cdots,0)) = \alpha_{ii} (x_i)^2$, for vectors with only one non-zero coordinate, but I had trouble proving that the $\alpha_{ij}$ are constants for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Are you working over general fields, or maybe just over the real numbers? (Usually the characterization you give is used by people working over more general base fields, or even base rings.)

Comment: @CaptainLama It says explicitly that we are working with real numbers.

Comment: @CaptainLama I was trying to prove it for real numbers, I didn't know it was valid for other fields.

Comment: To clarify my comment, my immediate use for the proposition is for real numbers, but I would be happy if someone provided a proof it applies to all number fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B(v,w)$ is a bilinear form, then $B(v,v)$ is a quadratic form. Observe that if $B(v,w)=f(v+w)-f(v)-f(w)$ then $B(v,v)=f(2v)-2f(v)=4f(v)-2f(v)=2f(v).$ Therefore $f(v)$ is a quadratic form.

Comment: The conclusion only works in characteristic not 2.

Comment: @CaptainLama I take for granted that OP meant real numbers.

Comment: It's very possible, but then it's a bit weird to add the homogeneity property, as it is automatic in that case. I asked the OP to be sure.

Comment: @CaptainLama In my answer I have used  the homogeneity assumption, namely $f(2v)=4f(v).$

Comment: @CaptainLama The homogeneity assumption is really needed. Consider one dimensional space. Assume $B(x,y)=2xy$ and let $f(x)=x^2+g(x),$ where $g$ is a discontinuous solution of the functional equation $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y).$ Then $f$ satisfies $2xy=f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)$ but $f(2x)\neq 4f(x)$ if $g(x)\neq 0.$

Comment: @CaptainLama but is it true for characteristic 2?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of a quadratic form in general, in particular over any (commutative) base ring. In that case the definition with polynomials does not really make sense since the module has no reason to be free.